# CSS3 disable background-size transition

Tags: html, css

I'm changing my background image multiple times using jQuery and added a transition effect:

```
.background-container  {
   -webkit-transition: background-image 3s linear;
   -moz-transition: background-image .3s linear;
   transition: background-image .3s linear;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

The transition works but it is also applied to the background-size (I think..) making the transition take longer than `.3s`. For example if one image is larger in height or width than the other, the transition takes longer as the image scales down.

Very weird... It isn't caused by my jQuery (i tested) and it works fine when using images of equal heights and widths.

How can this be fixed?

**Entire code:**

HTML:

```
<div class="background-container">
  <div class="box" data-img="some url to image"></div>
  <div class="box" data-img="some url to image"></div>
  <div class="box" data-img="some url to image"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.box').hover(function() {
    var imgUrl = $(this).attr("data-img");
    if (imgUrl !== "") {
        $('.background-container').css("background-image", "url(" + imgUrl + ")" );
    }
});
```

When hovering a `.box` the background image of the container changes. If one background image is larger, it takes longer than .3s for it to transition. This shouldn't happen because i don't have a transition for background-size.

Comment: There's not enough code here to reproduce your scenario. Can you add more so that we can see the problem in action?

Comment: add more info here. Your question is unclear..

Comment: @tyler ok I added more information to my question

Comment: iguess the time lapse is because new background-image has to load and then once loaded (so size is known) cover is applied. On slow connection and browser with plenty page opened, it can take a while. Beside, background-image won't take any transition since the value is not number (unless bg-gradient where values can be calculated from a value down to another by steps and time)

Comment: @GCyrillus thank you for details. The transition works however as fade in/fade out

Comment: To fix this, preload the image or set it off the view and then back in view on hover ;)

Comment: is it possible to preload background images part of css properties?

Comment: yes, if you use multiple background . for a fade effect you need numbers and you may use a pseudo and opacity from 0 to 1  2 examples . swap bg position or use pseudo for a fade effect ;)http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbygeO